File manager tree nesting
Hi folks i'm trying to create this file explorer-like thing the one in vs code sidebar, you can create files one the top level and create nested files by clicking on the plus icon in the already created file, and all of this works but now the product needs the nested items to be in the form of accordions.... that the main title under which the files are nested needs to be rendered as an accordion with still able to create more nested files inside it.... and even one of the children if needed should get converted to an accordion if the user clicks a new file in it, i tried implementing the accordion thing but was not able to, can somebody please help me, that no matter what level of nesting is there it should automatically render it as an accordion else a normal P tag
here is the code ->
import { Button } from '@/components/ui/button';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const FileTree = () => {
  const [files, setFiles] = useState([]);
  const [editing, setEditing] = useState(null);
  const [newFileName, setNewFileName] = useState('');

  const handleAddFile = (parentIndex = null) => {
    if (newFileName.trim() === '') return;

    const newFile = { name: newFileName, children: [] };

    if (parentIndex === null) {
      setFiles([...files, newFile]);
    } else {
      const newFiles = [...files];
      const addNestedFile = (file, idx) => {
        if (idx === parentIndex) {
          file.children.push(newFile);
        } else {
          file.children.forEach((child, childIdx) => {
            addNestedFile(child, `${idx}-${childIdx}`);
          });
        }
      };
      newFiles.forEach((file, idx) => addNestedFile(file, idx.toString()));
      setFiles(newFiles);
    }

    setNewFileName('');
    setEditing(null);
  };

  const handleDeleteFile = (index) => {
    setFiles(files.filter((_, i) => i !== index));
  };

  const handleDeleteNestedFile = (parentIndex, index) => {
    const newFiles = [...files];
    const deleteNestedFile = (file, idx) => {
      if (idx === parentIndex) {
        file.children = file.children.filter((_, i) => i !== index);
      } else {
        file.children.forEach((child, childIdx) => {
          deleteNestedFile(child, `${idx}-${childIdx}`);
        });
      }
    };
    newFiles.forEach((file, idx) => deleteNestedFile(file, idx.toString()));
    setFiles(newFiles);
  };
  

  const renderFileTree = (files, parentIndex = null) => {
    return files.map((file, index) => {
      const currentIndex = parentIndex === null ? index.toString() : `${parentIndex}-${index}`;
      console.log(file.children);
      return (
        
        <div key={currentIndex} style={{ marginLeft: parentIndex !== null ? 20 : 0, borderLeft: parentIndex !== null ? '2px solid #ccc' : 'none', paddingLeft: 10 }}>
          <div
            style={{ display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center' }}
          >
            <span
              onMouseEnter={() => setEditing(currentIndex)}
              className='my-2 border border-white rounded-md px-2 py-1 cursor-pointer hover:border-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-100 hover:text-gray-800'
            >
              {file.name}
            </span>
            {editing === currentIndex && (
              <>
                <button onClick={() => setEditing(`nested-${currentIndex}`)} style={{ marginLeft: 10 }}>+</button>
                <button onClick={() => parentIndex === null ? handleDeleteFile(index) : handleDeleteNestedFile(parentIndex, index)} style={{ marginLeft: 10 }}>x</button>
              </>
            )}
          </div>
         
          
          {editing === `nested-${currentIndex}` && (
            <div style={{ marginTop: 10 }}>
              <input
                value={newFileName}
                onChange={(e) => setNewFileName(e.target.value)}
                placeholder="Enter file name"
                ref={(input) => input && input.focus()}
                onKeyDown={(e) => {
                  if (e.key === 'Enter') {
                    handleAddFile(currentIndex);
                  }
                }}
              />
              <button onClick={() => handleAddFile(currentIndex)}>✔</button>
              <button onClick={() => setEditing(null)}>✖</button>
            </div>
          )}
          {file.children.length > 0 && renderFileTree(file.children, currentIndex)}
        </div>
      );
    });
  };

  return (
    <div className='pt-56 ml-28'>
      <div>
        <Button onClick={() => setEditing('new')}>Create File</Button>
      </div>
      {editing === 'new' && (
        <div style={{ marginTop: 10 }}>
          <input
            value={newFileName}
            onChange={(e) => setNewFileName(e.target.value)}
            placeholder="Enter file name"
            ref={(input) => input && input.focus()}
            onKeyDown={(e) => {
              if (e.key === 'Enter') {
                handleAddFile();
              }
            }}
          />
          <button onClick={() => handleAddFile()}>✔</button>
          <button onClick={() => setEditing(null)}>✖</button>
        </div>
      )}
      <div style={{ marginTop: 20 }}>
        {renderFileTree(files)}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default FileTree;

what the current thing looks like ->
(https://i.sstatic.net/EDyqhkkZ.png)](https://i.sstatic.net/EDyqhkkZ.png)
can somebody please help

https://github.com/sojinantony01/react-custom-tree.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-custom-tree
https://sojinantony01.github.io/react-custom-tree/
here is a sample implementation.

I've seen this but my need is not just to render the tree right its much more the user can at anytime create more accordions delete them, edit existing accordions, or just create normal files without nesting ,and all of this with custom icons and a lot more than just rendering a tree

Use the logic from github instead of just using the package!.
Creating and deleting the node is just about updating the JSON!
